# how to execute local method from Ext.Template and Ext.apply methods

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to execute a local method in Ext.Template context.

The method should be a member in the class.

I tried the following code and it doesn't work.

Someone know of can I pass the function member to onClick event?

```
    requires: ['Ext.XTemplate'],
    alias : 'widget.countlinkcolumn',
    func: 'this.handleFilter'
    renderer: function(val,metaData,rec,b,c,d,f){
        var categoryId = 3;
        var colTemplate = new Ext.Template(
            '<div class="drill_down_link grid_cell_link" style="cursor: pointer; float:right" onclick="{on_click}({categoryId})">{text}</div>' +
            '</div>');

        var tpl = colTemplate.apply({
            text: text,
            categoryId: categoryId,
            on_click: this.func,
        });
        return tpl;
    },

    handleFilter: function (categoryId) {
        console.log(categoryId);
    }, 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Never found an simple solution to this problem... The `XTemplate` can't directly call **ExtJS** code from it (it's actually already rendered in the `DOM`)...

The workaround we found is to render the `XTemplate` in a `View` (But you can do it with `apply()`) then listening to the `itemClick` event.

In the listener we get the `DOM` element and we can get some additional data from an attribute (eg: `data-categoryId`):

```
xtype: 'view',
listeners: {
    itemClick: 'onItemClick',
}
// Additional attribute (data-categoryId) that store the categoryId
tpl: '<div data-categoryId="{categoryId}" class="drill_down_link">{text}</div>'
```

Then in the listener we can use this additional attribute after we checked that the correct button was clicked (by his `class` name but you can use other attribute)

```
onItemClick: function(dataView, record, item, index, e, removeAll){
    var me = this,
        target = e && e.target,
        targetClass = target && target.getAttribute("class");

    //Clicked on link (identified by his class name)
    var isLink = targetClass && targetClass.indexOf("drill_down_link") >= 0;
    if(isLink){
        // Get the attribute value we setted in the XTemplate
        var categoryId = target.getAttribute('data-categoryId');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only clean method of doing it, which i always preferred as well